# Saving as gs:// or https:// for user's image. which way is recommendable?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase for my Android application.
Users have theirs profile images each.
but currently, I am saving their image to Firebase Storage and in Firebase Storage either.

Firebase Storage

```
/avatar1.png
/avatar2.png
/avatar3.png
```

Firebase Firestore

```
/user/AAA/profile_uri -> "gs://.../avatar1.png"
```

```
val gsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(document.data["profile_url"] as String)         
gsReference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
    val imageURL = it.toString()
    context?.let { it1 -> Glide.with(it1).load(imageURL).into(binding.imgProfileMypicture)
}}
```

but I think it is a big redandunt retrieving url from gs protocol at every users call.
So I would like to save raw https url to Firestore but it has a token on the tail of url like this: [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-pow-265e1.appspot.com/o/profile%2Favatar2.png?alt=media&token={token}](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-pow-265e1.appspot.com/o/profile%2Favatar2.png?alt=media&token=%7Btoken%7D)

My question is...

1. I don't know it is a recommendable to save raw url on Firestore.
2. If so, how to get a https url without calling downloadUrl from Storage API.
   What I have refered so far: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Using Firebase storage the most used and most recommended method is saving public Url of the file in the Cloud Firestore. There is a main reason for that.

When used `gs://` protocol performance of the application will decrease due to every time you call for the file, you have to resolve a promise to get the public link.

So for you questions,

1. It is recommended to save raw url on Firestore and it is a commonly use technique.
2. There is no any other method to retrieve public Url of the file rather than using `getDownloadURL()` method.